# Adding mid roll in VideoView With IMA Sdk

Tags: android, ads

I am trying to put mid roll ads in my android Project. At the current moment, i have set pre rolls. But i cant figure out how to put mid roll. I am referring to IMA Advanced sample project. I have gone through tons of website and other answers too. An example would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

For easier and smoother integrations of IMA ads, you can use the framework which was built upon Google's ExoPlayer, you can find details here:

https://github.com/googleads/google-media-framework-android

Comment: Hey mack, Thanks for the reply. But my organisation has asked me specially to use only VideoView and nothing else. :(